Hi I am have a problem
hi Ubuntu i switched

to Ubuntu  and when i have to install package when i go to open with another app a have only app store and file help me to find package installer please

please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

There are many methods to install applications in Ubuntu:
From the Synaptic Package Manager. From .deb packages not included in Synaptic. From a .bin file. From a .run file. From a .sh file. From a .elf file. From a .jar file. From a .tar file or a .tar.gz or .tar.bz2 file.
The Synaptic Package Manager is the most practical and easy to use for new users, allowing you to install programs using repositories from the Internet or from a CD/DVD.
From .deb packages, once the .deb package has been downloaded, we go to the folder where we have the program, open a terminal and run cd ~/Downloads, we can use:
The dpkg command with the -i parameter followed by the package name plus the .deb extension. sudo dpkg -i file.deb.
The apt command with the package name plus the .deb extension, preceded by the path. sudo apt ~/Downloads/file.deb.
From .bin files, once the file has been downloaded, we go to the folder where we have the program, open a terminal and execute cd ~/Downloads, and use:
sudo chmod +x file.bin
sudo ./file.bin

From .run files, once the file has been downloaded, we go to the folder where we have the program, open a terminal and execute cd ~/Downloads, and use:
sudo chmod +x file.run
sudo ./file.run

From .sh files, once the file has been downloaded, we go to the folder where we have the program, open a terminal and execute cd ~/Downloads, and use:
sudo chmod +x file.sh
sudo ./file.sh

From .elf files, once the file has been downloaded, we go to the folder where we have the program, We open a terminal and run cd ~/Downloads, and use:
sudo chmod +x file.elf
sudo ./file.elf

Jar files are programs written in Java that, in order to run on any operating system, require the Java virtual machine, Java Runtime Environment or OpenJDK to be installed.
Once the jar file has been downloaded, we go to the folder where we have the program, open a terminal and run cd ~/Downloads, and use:
sudo chmod +x file.jar
java -jar file.jar

The .tar, .tar.gz or .tar.bz2 files are compressed folders that usually contain the program in source code.
Sometimes it is enough to unzip the folder and run the executable file it contains, and most of the time they have to be compiled from a terminal.
An example of these programs that run as soon as the folder is unzipped are: Firefox and Thunderbird
